# PHP MYSQL Collation Speical Characters XML->PHP->MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, collation

I am trying to import data from an XML file into a MYSQL DB using PHP. I am able to get the code to work just fine but when I look at the data in the DB there are special characters. For example, when I look at the XML in my browser it shows up as "outdoors in good weater..." but in the DB it appears to as "outdoors in good weatherâ€¦".

I've cycled through all the different types of collation for that field in my DB but it does not seem to help much. Sometimes it shows up with the characters mentioned above and others as ???.

I have also tried to sync up the data with the following code in my PHP

```
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");
```

But, again I have had no luck.

Thank you for reading this and for your help!

Akshay

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the character set to UTF-8, along with your collation:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

What you are seeing is a Unicode ellipsis character (…) being converted into another character set, which is probably Latin1. That is why it looks garbled.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ran the script you gave me on my DB and the appropriate table but it didn't change the way the characters showed up. I truncated my table and re-imported the XML file again and I go the same results. Do you have any other ideas?